# Parse.com push notification badge value

Tags: ios, push-notification, badge, parse-platform

I use [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and the [iOS Parse Framework](http://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart) in an iOS app. I want to send a push notification to a channel, but I would like the value of the badge to be set to `1`, even if the user receives multiple notifications.

Here is the code used to send the notification, taken from the documentation :

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Here is the content of the notification !", @"alert",
    @"Increment", @"badge",
    @"cheering.caf", @"sound",
    nil];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannels:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A Channel", nil]];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Here is [what they say](http://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/iOS) (go to "Sending options" > "Customizing your notifications") about the value of the `badge` key in the dictionary :

> **badge:** *(iOS only)* the value indicated in the top right corner of the app icon. **This can be set to a value** or to Increment in order to increment the current value by 1.

So obviously, the value `@"Increment"` works fine, but I want to always set the badge value to "`1`".

What is the correct syntax ? I can't seem to find it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an NSNumber. I.e.

```
[push setData:@{
    @"alert": @"Here is the content of the notification !",
    @"badge": @1,
    @"sound": @"cheering.caf"}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I can, just to make sure it works ;)